# Rails action caching and json responses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, memcached

I am having problems responding with JSON to json request, while having action caching enabled.

I have a fairly simple controller which responds to both JSON and HTML and caching works fine for HTML response, but I noticed when I request JSON, and would normally respond with JSON, but with action cache enabled, it wraps the JSON output in the layout!

When I cleared the cache, it gives me an error that no default layout exists:

> ArgumentError in ClipsController#index
>
> There was no default layout for ClipsController in...

How do I return JSON for the cached action?

UPDATE, I suspect the error about layout has to do with the way I cache the actions:

`caches_action :index, :layout => false`

I'm not sure though, why it would still need a layout in the case of a JSON response, as without caching there is no problem.

temporarily I have modified the cache filter to not cache for JSON requests, but this is not an ideal work-around, what do I do if I do want to cache JSON?

`caches_action :index, :layout => false, :if => Proc.new { |c| !c.request.format.json? }`

Comment: Interesting problem! I've spent some time digging on this, and it appears to be a bug that was added in Rails 3... I couldn't get this to work properly for me, but http://blog.blazingcloud.net/2010/11/21/caching-in-rails/ mentions putting layout: false in your before_filter, which might alleviate your issues. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Thank you. Your workaround did the trick for my Rails 3.2.8 app. I'm caching JS requests in the browser now, just added response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=600, must-revalidate" on the controller and "cache: true" at Jquery.Ajax request.

Comment: I suppose that you have you tried `render json: ` when you want to specifically return JSON?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Same case here. Looks like a bug. Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this might actually be a bug with action caching, but perhaps there's something I'm not understanding.

See [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/actions.rb#L152) to see where it goes wrong.  Basically, if you've set the layout option to false, it doesn't care, and tries to render it with a layout anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem (rendering HTML via an ajax request, layout is set to false but is present)

Here's a workaround : create an empty layout and use it to serve ajax request

```
# app/views/layout/empty.html.erb
<%= yield %>

# controller
class FooController ...
  layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.xhr? ? "empty" : "your normal html layout" }
  caches_action ...
end
```